# как сделать так чтобы textarea имел размеры текста внутри него

Tags: html, css

как сделать так чтобы textarea имел размеры текста внутри него, то есть текст всегда полностью отображался, и не было прокрутки в середине texarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, нужно автоматическое увеличение по высоте. [@SDmitriyS](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=1137890#answers_list_answer) предложил следующий вариант:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (this.scrollTop > 0) {
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea style="overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
```